# Django: How to get a users coordinates (latitude, longitude) in a view?

Tags: python, django, django-views, geolocation

I need to be able to check the user's location before determining where their redirect will be sent. Is there an easy way to do this in Django/Python?

views.py

```
@login_required
def update(request):
    if users coords in range(....):
       form = UpdateForm(request.POST or None)
       if request.method == "POST":
           if form.is_valid():
               update = form.save(commit=False)
               update.user = request.user
               update.save()
               value = form.cleaned_data['update']
               return redirect('main-home')
       return render(request, "main/update.html", {'form': form})
   else:
       return render(request, "main/error.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
   from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP

    g = GeoIP() 
    lat,lng = g.lat_lon(user_ip)
```

Comment: How did you get the user_ip ?

Comment: @RobyB using request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR")